# NuGet Package for Xamarin Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package, portable-class-library

How does one go about and create a NuGet package for a Xamarin Portable Class Library Project.

Firstly, I selected the following Project Template for my Project

[image]

Under Build section in Visual Studio, the following Platforms are targeted

[image]

My NuGet Package Explorer project looks like the following

[image]

I am attempting to create a NuGet package using the NuGet Package Explorer tool for my Class Library. However, I do not want to upload a broken package to NuGet and thus seek some expert advice.

Comment: Is your Peter.App.dll just a Portable Class Library (PCL) assembly? If so you do not need to have the MonoAndroid, Xamarin.iOS10 and the wpa81 folders. Also I would check the PCL profile your project is targeting since the screenshot shows Windows Phone 8.1 (wpa81) but the portable directory does not include this. Profile 78 or 256 are good ones to use.

Comment: @MattWard Thank you Matt. The library mostly deals with Xml content and doesn't depend on any special external reference. I am kinda new to Xamarin, so I am a little curious to know if my directory selection in NuGet Package Explorer would prevent certain Xamarin developers from downloading the package.

Comment: I would suggest using Profile259 (edit your .csproj so it uses that) and then your NuGet package would have just the one directory: `portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8` with your assembly. The assembly can then be used by all Xamarin mobile frameworks as well as Windows Phone and Windows 8.

Comment: @MattWard I am gonna do just that. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated!